# drawing a 45 degrees reference line as well as making x and y axis equal range

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am trying to make the following scatterplot:

[image]

To something that has X and Y axis equal range as well as overlaying a 45 degree reference line on the scatterplot.
I have this code but produces a plot that is not my expectation. How can I fix it?

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
#ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')

plt.scatter(actuals.cpu(), predictions.cpu(), cmap='viridis')
plt.xlabel('Ground Truth')
plt.ylabel('Predictions')
plt.axis('equal')
xpoints = ypoints = plt.xlim()
plt.plot(xpoints, ypoints, linestyle='--', color='k', lw=3, scalex=False, scaley=False)
plt.savefig('predictions_actuals_scatterplot.png')
```

Here are my Python and matplotlib versions:

```
$ python
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'3.5.1'
```

[image]

If I just use the following code, while the origin is met by the 45 degree line, still is not exactly what I am looking for.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.scatter(actuals.cpu(), predictions.cpu(), cmap='viridis')
plt.xlabel('Ground Truth')
plt.ylabel('Predictions')
xpoints = ypoints = plt.xlim()
plt.plot(xpoints, ypoints, linestyle='--', color='k', lw=3, scalex=False, scaley=False)
plt.savefig('predictions_actuals_scatterplot.png')
```

[image]

Comment: What is your expectation?  You haven't told us what you WANT.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have written my expectation in the title, to have equal range X and Y axes as well as overlaying a 45-degree reference line on the scatter plot.

Comment: You HAVE a 45 degree reference line.  Your X data and Y data do not have equal ranges.  The X range is very, very narrow.  You can certainly set the axes limits manually.

Comment: do you know why the 45-degree line doesn't pass through the origin?

Comment: Ah I think I see.  You don't actually want the axes to have equal ranges.  You want the data to fill the plot.  You should probably remove `plt.axis('equal')`, and just let matplotlib determine the ranges.

Comment: It doesn't pass through the origin because you didn't tell it to.  You set the ends of the line to the extremes of the X data.  The X data only runs  from 0.24 to 0.43.

Comment: That's what I originally had but it doesn't make them equal range for both x and y axes

Comment: Please stop using the term "equal range".  That's not what you want at all.  Your X data has a range of 0.24 to 0.43.  Your Y data has a much larger range, from -0.4 to 1.2.  What you want is for the plot to be filled.  It would be easier for us to help if you gave us the data.

Comment: @TimRoberts can you please take a look at the last update in my original question?

Comment: You say "still not exactly what I'm looking for", but we can't tell what you ARE looking for.  Perhaps you should draw it on a piece of paper and post the image.  Because your ranges are so different, you either get "45 degree line and X data squished", or "X data spread out and non-45 degree line".  Those are the choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are wanting?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate random data.

x = np.random.random(120) * 0.21 + 0.24
y = np.random.random(120) * 1.4 - 0.2
ticks = np.arange( -0.2, 1.2, step=0.2 )

plt.scatter(x, y, cmap='viridis')
plt.xticks( ticks )
plt.yticks( ticks )
plt.plot( [-.2,1.2], [-.2,1.2], linestyle='--', color='k' )
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: The new [plt.axline()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axline.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axline), e.g. `plt.axline((0,0), slope=1)` might also be interesting here. That will draw a line until it touches the borders.

Comment: I didn't know about that.  Matplotlib can do just about anything, as long as you can describe what you want...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the plt.axis('equal') request is applied when the figure is rendered, which is *after* you call plt.xlim(). The solution I suggest is below, which uses both plt.xlim() as well as plt.ylim(). In this way, you do not have to know about the input data ranges in advance.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

rng = np.array([0.2, 1.5])
offset = np.array([0.25, -0.2])

xy = np.random.rand(30, 2) * rng + offset

plt.scatter(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], label="points")
plt.axis("equal")

left, right = plt.xlim()
bottom, top = plt.ylim()
axlim = (min(bottom, left), max(top, right))

# you can see the problem here: you've requested
# axes equal, but that has not yet been applied
# to the axes.
print(f"bottom={bottom}, top={top}, left={left}, right={right}")
print(f"Axis limits: {axlim}")

# better solution
xpoints2 = ypoints2 = np.linspace(axlim[0], axlim[1])
plt.plot(xpoints2, ypoints2, color="m", label="xlim and ylim")

# equivalent to the non-working solution
xpoints = ypoints = np.linspace(left, right)
plt.plot(xpoints, ypoints, color="g", label="xlim")

print(f"{left} {right}")
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Example output:

[image: Example output]

Comment: can you show the plot you get as a result of your code in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `plt.xticks()` and `plt.yticks()`, then pass the values for the axis limits separated by comma?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).